# Unresolved Import in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

https://pastebin.com/2TXGSDLw

```
               Perform the action.
                 match action {
    Add { text } => tasks::add_task(journal_file, Task::new(text)),
    List => tasks::list_tasks(journal_file),
    Done { position } => tasks::complete_task(journal_file, position),
```

https://pastebin.com/zb0CCDWT

I've been working on this CLI for what seems like 8 hours. One more error seems to get in my way and while it seems simple enough I can't fix it. Unresolved module and it can't find the path to my task.rs file.

Comment: Rust uses Folder structures to identify where modules are located. I would advise you to:
1 add the information for what your file structure is, and
2 if you haven't yet, check out the modules chapter in the rust book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch07-03-paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree.html

Comment: Please dont remove your questions as it can help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from the screenshots you’ve uploaded. It seems the problem might be the name of your struct.

You have a code under task.rs:

```
pub struct tasks {...}
```

and then below it

```
impl Task {...}
```

I think it’s also recommended having structs with names starting with a capital letter.

PS.
Perhaps copy and paste the code in your post next time? Others might easily see the problem you’re facing. Or perhaps they can copy and paste the codes you’ve posted with the fix as well.

Comment: Thanks man! and yes will do. I think I changed it while trying to debug and my bad I should've just copy and pasted

Comment: I went for a pastebin so that it's easy to copy on both .rs files

Comment: Alright, you're welcome! Not sure how stackoverflow works for now, I think you need to close this question or something ? Then I'll get points maybe? Hahaha I'll be adding my contributions here in my resume =,D

Comment: Not close, but see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.